# How to load gems from local sub-directory?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a project (see https://github.com/marick/growing-oo-software-in-ruby ) where the Gems are all under a local directory /third-party
However, in my Ruby 1.9 environment, I have problems loading the gems for running the examples ...

To understand what goes worng, I want to learn on requires and usage of rubygems. For this, I made a setup like:

```
   .
   |____env
   | |____gem
   | | |____gems
   | | | |____testgem.rb
   |____sandbox.rb
   |____src
   | |____foo
   | | |____foo.rb
```

How can sandbox be used to actually require testgem.rb and made it accessible to foo.rb ?
There is a special case for a gem like flexmock. 
Assuming testgem.rb would look like:

```
   require 'flexmock/base'
   require 'flexmock/test_unit_integration'
```

How would foo.rb get access to sub-files of testgem.rb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like `require 'foo'`, Ruby looks in your `loadpath` to find this source file.

You would probably find interest in this article, http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/9/1/gem-packaging-best-practices

Your `loadpath` is just an array, which in 1.9 is aliased to `$:` - you could add to it like so:

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path("../../env/gem/gems", __FILE__)
require "testgem"
```

Comment: yes, with a minor modification, I get it working:  $:.unshift File.expand_path("./env/gem/gems", File.dirname(__FILE__))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
require "rubygems"
Gem.use_paths(nil, Gem.path << "../../env/gem/gems")
require "testgem"
```

Comment: hmm... although i like the approach, I get a LoadError: no such file to load -- testgem

Comment: Maybe the path would be `"./env/gem/gems"`, like the other answer. :)